# Subtract two variables in unix

Tags: shell, unix, aix

This is my script which I am running on UNIX(AIX):

```
$MON date +"%m"
echo 'expr $MON - 2'
```

Output:

```
04
expr $MON - 2
```

I just want to subtract 2 from my current month and display .

Comment: So in case the month is 0 or 1, what you want to show?

Answer (score 2):

I realize that the default shell on `AIX` is some variant of `ksh` which doesn't suffer from the same deficiency as `bash` in the input base, but it is something to bear in mind if you end up encountering this on another platform.

If this is your input:

```
$MON date +"%m"
echo 'expr $MON - 2'
```

then you have several issues.

- `$MON` is unset, which causes the invocation of the line `date +"%m"`, which gives the output `04`
- the echo command does not execute the expr command as you're using the wrong kind of ticks, which causes the output `expr $MON - 2`

First, to assign the variable you do `VARIABLE=value`, in your case this should be:

```
MON=`date +"%m"`
```

Don't put a space before or after the `=` sign.

Secondly, to perform the expr, you need to use the backtick(`` ` ``)

```
echo `expr $MON - 2`
```

However, for most shells, you should use the more modern version of *i want to get the result of a command*, which is the logic `$(command)`. These can be embedded, which makes them a lot easier to understand (backticks require escaping, and the more backticks the more escaping needed which quickly leads to backslash-palooza).
For bash, you need to ensure that the month is interpreted as a base 10 number, as otherwise once you hit August the code will stop working:

To force the number to be interpreted as a base 10 number, precede it with `10#`:

```
MON=10#$(date +"%m")
echo $(($MON-2))
```

Examples:

```
bash-3.2$ month=07
bash-3.2$ echo $(($month + 1))
8
bash-3.2$ month=08
bash-3.2$ echo $(($month + 1))
bash: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
bash-3.2$ month=10#08
bash-3.2$ echo $(($month + 1))
9
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MON=$(date +"%m")
echo $(($MON-2))
```

You don't need to use `expr` because bash can perform simple arithmetic as well.

If your shell doesn't support arithmetic expressions, use `expr`:

```
expr $MON - 2
```

In both cases, you will get `2` as the output.

Comment: --2")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
as output .                                                                Thats the output .

Comment: You haven't assigned MON correctly. Use `MON=$(date +"%m")` as shown in my answer.

Comment: @DeepeshShetty - what shell are you using? This answer is correct for the shells I tried

Answer (score 1):

Another option: if you want to see 11 or 12 in January or February, let GNU `date` do the arithmetic:

```
date -d "-2 months" +%m
```